# URL Key Not Automatically Generating When Importing Products in Magento 1.8.1.0

Tags: magento

I have imported around 60 products onto a newly installed Magento website.

In the past, I never entered in any information in the url_key and url_path columns of a CSV before importing products. In the past, the URL Key was automatically generated.

However with my first installation of 1.8.1.0, when I import products--even though they successfully import--they do not automatically generate a URL Key, and are therefore not showing up on the category pages they should appear on.

I have noticed that if I click through to a product in the Magento Admin Panel, and then save the product--even if I do not make any changes--a URL Key will be generated, and then the product will show up on the category page.

If it is not possible to generate the URL Key when importing products, how would I go about adding URL-friendly information in the url_key and url_path columns of the CSV?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I have solved this issue. I accidentally installed a template made for 1.7 on a new 1.8 install. I have just reinstalled Magento as version 1.7.

Comment: Could you explain in more detail, how you solved this issue?

Answer (score 2):

I think you have not added **_product_websites** field and value as **base** for single website/store in your import csv file.  I added this field in my csv, the URL key is generated and working good.

Comment: I have this in my csv file and still url key is not generated